# In the Files GUI of Ubuntu 18.04, is there a way to see the space of folders without installing adds-ons that might restart your computer?

Tags: 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic and the Files GUI will only show how many items are inside a folder, not the disk space it occupies in Kb, Mb, etc. I am wondering why it is so hard to get it to show? Was there a historical reason? I currently do not want to restart the computer as I am tunneling into it due to the Coronavirus and was wondering if there was a way to get it to show the disk space a folder took up in the Files columns. Thanks!

Comment: @user535733 for folders that column only shows the number of items in a folder, not the actual space taken by files, folders and subfolders (which requires a calculation)

Comment: @vanadium you are, of course, quite correct. Thanks for straightening me out on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see space occupied by a folder and all its contents (i.e. files, folders and subfolder with files contained theirein) in the properties dialog of the folder. With the folder highlighted, either

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd>, or
- right-click the folder and select "Properties"

You will see the total space occupied by any items in that folder and its subfolders, along with the free space remaining on the partition where the folder resides.